# How to define an interface method to accept a class or any of its subclasses in Java?

Tags: java, interface

Suppose I have a class called Animal and an interface called AnimalTrainer.

```
public interface AnimalTrainer
 {
    void trainAnimal(Animal animal);
 }
```

Now, the problem arises when I want to write an implementation that trains only Lion, for example, where Lion extends Animal.

```
public class LionTrainer implements AnimalTrainer
 {
    public void trainAnimal(Lion lion)
      {
         // code 
      }
 }
```

But this doesn't work. How can I define the trainAnimal method in AnimalTrainer such that the above LionTrainer implementation is possible? Or would I have to change the LionTrainer implementation?

Comment: (I have to point out that `AnimalTrainer` should be a role. A single `AnimalTrainer` instnace should be able to do `LionTraining` and `AntTraining`.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Ok. The above example was just for illustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to type AnimalTrainer

```
public interface AnimalTrainer<T extends Animal>
 {
    public void trainAnimal(T animal);
 }

public class LionTrainer implements AnimalTrainer<Lion>
 {
    public void trainAnimal(Lion lion);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use generics:

```
public interface AnimalTrainer<T extends Animal> {
   void trainAnimal(T animal);
}
class LionTrainer implements AnimalTrainer<Lion> {
   public void trainAnimal(Lion lion) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use generic types...

```
public interface AnimalTrainer<T extends Animal>
 {
    public void trainAnimal(T animal);
 }
```

then `LionTrainer implements AnimalTrainer<Lion>` ...

Comment: or any of the two other answers posted as I was typing :D